# Getting error while declaring a constant in Interface

Tags: apex

```
public interface Constants{
    String TEST = 'test';

}
```

I am getting below error -

```
Error: Compile Error: expecting a left parentheses, found '=' at line 2 column 16
```

Can someone explain why am i getting this error?

Comment: You may have thought you could do that because Java supports constants in interfaces, but Apex does not.  Depending on your use case you might want to consider [Custom Labels](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cl_about.htm) or [Custom Settings](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cs_about.htm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Interfaces](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_interfaces.htm) should have only method declarations. If you think you need member variables within this new type you're creating - you most likely want to make a class that you'll extend later on. Probably even an [abstract class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_keywords_super.htm)?

```
public abstract class Constants{
    String TEST = 'test';
}
```

I fail to understand how someone might think he later needs to write `class MyConstants extends Constants` (or `implements` if you'd follow the interface path)...

Please don't name your classes or variables `Test`, this can lead to some interesting compilation errors ;) And last but not least - this should probably be a `public static final String testString...`

Answer (score 5):

You can't declare a constant in an interface, or for that matter implement any code other than method signatures (which you must then implement in a Class). An interface is a fairly generic term across programming languages. You can read about it in general here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)

Or, specifically in Apex here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_interfaces.htm

However, it looks like you might want an enum (or a class) though for what you're doing, you can read up on that here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_enums.htm

Or if you simply want it as a class:

```
    public class Constants {
        public static final TEST = 'test';
}
```

So you can access it elsewhere as:

```
Constants.TEST;
```